# Extension of scala collections with composite bounded generic types

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scala-collections, generic-collections, higher-kinded-types

I'm rather new to Scala, and I feel like I've jumped into the Scala deep end.  I need to write a couple (err, extend) of collections (one similar to ArrayBuffer and one similar to Array) that works with generic (but bounded) types.  I have an idea about how to go about this, but it's entirely possible that my whole approach is wrong too.

The essence of what I'm trying to do should be clear from the code below.  I want to be able to make a collection of "composite objects" with each component object bounded by a certain type.  In the code below, the `Meal` object can be `Meal[Beef, Broccoli]` but cannot be `Meal[Carrots, Broccoli]`.  Then, I want to make two collection classes (Buffer-like and IndexedSeq-like) for the composite object.  As a reference, I have been using [The Architecture of Scala Collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html).

```
package food

import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import collection.{mutable, IndexedSeqLike}
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

// basic objects
abstract class Food {
  val isCooked: Boolean
}
abstract class Protein extends Food
abstract class Vegetable extends Food

case class Beef(isCooked: Boolean) extends Protein
case class Fish(isCooked: Boolean) extends Protein

case class Carrots(isCooked: Boolean) extends Vegetable
case class Broccoli(isCooked: Boolean) extends Vegetable

// Composite Object
class Meal[Protein, Vegetable](protein: Protein, vegetable: Vegetable)

// Buffer Container
class MealsBuffer[Protein, Vegetable] extends ArrayBuffer[Meal[Protein, Vegetable]]

// Fixed-Size Container
final class MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable] private (data: Array[Meal[Protein, Vegetable]])
  extends IndexedSeq[Meal[Protein, Vegetable]]
  with IndexedSeqLike[Meal[Protein, Vegetable], MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable]] {

  import MealsSeq._

  // Mandatory re-implementation of `newBuilder` in `IndexedSeq`
  override protected[this] def newBuilder: mutable.Builder[Meal[Protein, Vegetable], MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable]] = MealsSeq.newBuilder

  // Mandatory implementation of `apply` in `IndexedSeq`
  def apply(idx: Int): Meal[Protein, Vegetable] = {
    if (idx < 0 || length <= idx)
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException
    data(idx)
  }

  def length: Int = data.size

}

// Fixed-Size Container Companion Object
object MealsSeq { 

  def fromBuffer(buf: MealsBuffer[Protein, Vegetable]): MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable] = fromIndexedSeq(buf.toArray)

  def fromBuffer(buf: ArrayBuffer[Meal[Protein, Vegetable]]): MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable] = fromIndexedSeq(buf.toArray)

  def fromIndexedSeq(buf: Array[Meal[Protein, Vegetable]]): MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable] = new MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable](buf)

  def fromSeq(buf: Seq[Meal[Protein, Vegetable]]): MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable] = new MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable](buf.toArray)

  def apply(bases: Meal[Protein, Vegetable]*) = fromSeq(bases)

  def newBuilder: mutable.Builder[Meal[Protein, Vegetable], MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable]] = new ArrayBuffer mapResult fromSeq

  implicit def canBuildFrom: CanBuildFrom[MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable], Meal[Protein, Vegetable], MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable]] =
    new CanBuildFrom[MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable], Meal[Protein, Vegetable], MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable]] {
      def apply(): mutable.Builder[Meal[Protein, Vegetable], MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable]] = newBuilder
      def apply(from: MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable]): mutable.Builder[Meal[Protein, Vegetable], MealsSeq[Protein, Vegetable]] = newBuilder
  }
}
```

This code does not compile, and as I indicate, I especially run into trouble in the companion object, specifically with regard to implementing generics in a singleton object.

As I said, I am open to what I've laid out ultimately *not* being the right solution to what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish.  Should I somehow be using traits instead of abstract classes? Implicit conversions instead of bounded generics and polymorphism?  Is there a way to enforce what I'm trying to do with composition rather than inheritance for the composite `Meals` object?  Is this somehow a place to use higher kinded types?  Scala has so much that Java doesn't, my head is sort of spinning.

**Update**

To clarify, the scope of what I need to do is the following: I need two collections, one Array-like and one ArrayBuffer-like.  The collections hold an entity comprised by a pair of sub-entities, each sub-entity having specific restrictions.  In the example here, the collections are for a Meal made up of only one Protein and only one Vegetable.  The collections will eventually need to be extended with specialized behavior and methods, also with the ability to override particular implementations of methods to make them more efficient for the particular use case.  That's the extent of the task.  I'm just looking for the easiest way to accomplish it.

Comment: It's not clear from here what the underlying problem you're trying to solve is. Why do you need custom collection types? If it's just the convenience of `S[A,B]` rather than `S[M[A,B]]`, then a type alias may serve. If you need to add specialised methods, then implicit conversions with bounds may help. However, it's hard to tell just from the information here.

Comment: @Impredicative I've added an update to try and give some additoinal clarification (not sure if I actually _did_ clarify anything for you though). Specialized and/or overriden methods of these collections are a must for the long-term plan. I don't necessarily care about the convenience of `S[A,B]` over `S[M[A,B]]`. The important point is that A is a special type, with restricted subtypes; and the same for B. Using type `ArrayBuffer[(A,B)]` and/or creating an alias for it doesn't work because I eventually want to be able to override methods, and Array is a final class in scala.

Comment: How about subclassing from `ArrayBuffer` and `WrappedArray`?